# Reporting in Excel 2010 with VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

How can I do this please!?
I have an excel work book with 60 sheets and all 60 have the same column headers and number of columns.

Each sheet is the name of a country and the rows has names in column A and a status in B and a code D

I need to produce a report using all the 60 sheets that list all the Names by Country where value B =  “XYV” and show the corresponding Value in D.

Hope that makes sense!

I have been trying to use a pivot table across the sheet but I either get Invalid reference if I only select the columns needed (and this takes forever to do!) or insufficient memory if I select the whole sheet.

Can I do this in VBA macro?

Sorry I'm new to Excel in this way so any help would be appreciated…

Comment: to retrieve that data you could use VLookup, or INDIRECT with MATCH formulas - take a look at [Excel User MVP](http://exceluser.com/blog/465/excels-best-lookup-method-index-match.html)

Comment: Thanks Philip I will take a read of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VBA, this works (although it needs tidying up - I've included it to give you the idea):

```
Sub FindItems()

Const Thing As String = "XYV"

'remember which workbook you are on
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'create new book for answer
Dim AnswerBook As Workbook
Set AnswerBook = Workbooks.Add

'loop over sheets in original workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim BCells As Range

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

    'check each cell in column B
    wb.Activate
    ws.Select

    Range("B1").Select
    Set BCells = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))

    For Each c In BCells

        If LCase(c.Value) = LCase(Thing) Then

            'add to list
            AnswerBook.Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = ws.Name
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = c.Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        End If
    Next c

Next ws
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you after changing some of the values to meet my needs this worked great :)